# Angular: Bind function from child to parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Normally we give a child-directive a callback function which it can call if something happens. In my case, its the other way around; I would like to inform the directive about something. I'm still using angular 1.4 (but soon I'll move to 1.5 and eventually to 2). With this in mind I would like to avoid things like `$watch` and `$broadcast`.

So, I think there are two solution: 1) use a service and 2) bind a callback function from the child to the parent

1) Although this might be the preferred solution I see two problems
    a) A whole service for such a simple task
    b) you'll need `$watch` to detect the change

2) Well, this solution sounds super easy, but it seems to be more complicated than I expected or maybe it is not even possible :(

Here is my test code:

```
<button ng-click="mycontroller.callback()">Click me</button> 
<bar-foo activate-me="mycontroller.callback"></bar-foo>
```

So, `mycontroller` doesn't have a function `callback`, but the directive `bar-foo` does

```
angular.module('HelloApp')
    .directive('barFoo', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                activateMe: '='
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.activateMe = function () {
                    this.activated = true
                }
            },
            template: '<p ng-if="activated">Activated</p>'
        }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvzgpn5j/7/)

Is what I'm trying possible ? or should I accept that `services` are the one and only way to tackle this or is there more ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What exactly would you like controller to inform directive about?

Comment: In my case the directive show some content based on an id, which is a string. In the footer I have a couple of buttons which can change this, meaning that if you click a button, the directive should receive this new id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are thinking too hard here. While it is possible to give outer controller a function to call and notify directive directly (which you *should not* do), much more straightforward and and natural approach is to use input binding. In your case it will be as simple as:

```js
angular.module('HelloApp', []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  this.callBarFoo = function() {
    this.callback = true;
  }
});

angular.module('HelloApp')
  .directive('barFoo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        activateMe: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {

      },
      template: '<p ng-if="activateMe">Activated</p>'
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="HelloApp" data-ng-controller="MyCtrl as mycontroller">
  <button ng-click="mycontroller.callBarFoo()">Click me</button>
  
  <bar-foo activate-me="mycontroller.callback"></bar-foo>
</div>
```

In general, controller is supposed to let directive know about data whenever it is appropriate. This is recommended data flow direction: from controller -> into directive. Directive should never ask for data itself. It's controller who decides when and what to pass into directive. When directive might need some data - then two-way binding can be used.

Related reading I put together [here](http://dfsq.info/site/read/angular-components-communication).

Comment: Well, true. But what if you need to do more than just that, like loading a resource for example ?

Comment: Sure. But who needs to load a resource? - Of course controller. So it load a resource, data, etc. Then lets directive know about this data. This is recommended data flow direction. Directive should never ask for data itself. Controller decides when to pass it into directive.

Comment: ok, good point, you nailed one of my arguments :) But what if you want to apply transitions if a change happens. Then you must need to use $watch, am I right ?

Comment: What kind of transition? you mean CSS of .. what? something in directive template?

Comment: Anyway, there is already change detection mechanism in place that Angular  runs (digest loops). They are triggered for you whenever anything changes. Then you simple can make use of ngShow/ngHide directives that are wired to ngAnimate service. Then with couple of CSS rules you can implement any transition. Directive and controller don't even need to know how data change is reflected UI-wise. Thanks to separation of CSS and JS with the help of ngAnimate bridge.

Comment: Do you mean that if data is changing, angular will use ngAnimate on the element to which the change applies use things like `ng-leave` and `ng-enter` ? Furthermore, and that is the last thing, I need to $element.scrollTop(0) the element, thats not css unfortunately I guess.

Comment: I mean directives like ngShow/Hide, ngIf/Switch, ngRepeat are wired to ngAnimate, so you can easily implement transitions with them. `$element.scrollTop(0)` you can use from inside of your directive, it's okay.

Comment: ok, I see. But to know when to run $element.scrollTop(0) (which should be done on a change) can only be triggered with a $watch right?

Comment: Yes, in this case you will need to set up watcher yourself using $scope.$watch in directive link/controller function.

Answer (score 0):

The one alternative way I know it is to attach some id to directive root element . 
Then from your controller you can do so .

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('the-id')).scope().directiveFunction(args);
```

Comment: Not a best way to solve the problem . But it does the work.

Comment: No, it does not solve a problem, however it **does** create a problem, making application low-quality piece of tangled crap. In this single line of code, you packed at least two problems: component (directive) encapsulation violation via direct DOM access, and architectural flaw because component should never request data controller. (Not to mention, it could have been written it least as `scope.$parent` instead of what you wrote). No offence, but this is extremely bad what you are suggesting.